# PHP class size vs opcache?

Tags: php, opcache

I have a potentially very large (several megabytes perhaps) PHP class, generated of course. Is there any setting or limitation that would cause opcache slowdown in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check opcache.max_file_size option. This option can set a maximum file size to cache. Thus, big files can be skipped by opcode cacher. However, it defaults to 0, meaning all files will be cached.

Next option to check is opcache.max_accelerated_files. For big projects with Twig and annotations default value 2000 is not enought. Consider to increase it.

And the last one is opcache.memory_consumption. I noticed, that after reaching this limit, opcache won't add new items into the cache. So, increase it to 256M or 512M.

Comment: Is there a way to find out when either the maximum amount of files or memory it hit?

Answer (score 0):

Few things make OPCache slow, like opcache.consistency_checks if is it enabled, OPcache will verify the cache checksum every N requests, where N is the value of this configuration directive. For your large file size i am sure it is not good idea to enable this.

Also, if you doubt that it is effecting OPCache, why can't you try tools like OpCacheGUI to check it.

Comment: Because what I can try is likely limited. For example, if it slows down on PHP 5.4 under Windows I certainly won't be able to test it. I need either examples of how to fix when it slows down or authoritative answer that it won't.

Comment: Ok then, best thing refer this web page http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/zendserverapi/zend_opcache-configuration_directives.htm Few things to note down is, opcache.optimization_level , opcache.save_comments (disable it to reduce the file size), opcache.enable_cli (Disable this for try) and also consider what Alexander and I specified.